# How to correctly style sticky table header?

Tags: html, css, angular, css-tables

I have a little problem with style sticky header in my data table. I wrote simple Angular component and specific directive:

**sticky.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[sticky]'
})
export class StickyDirective {

    constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _window: WindowRef) {
        console.log('debug')
    }

    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    handleScrollEvent(e) {
        if (this._window.nativeWindow.pageYOffset > 100) {
            this._element.nativeElement.classList.add('stick');
        } else {
            this._element.nativeElement.classList.remove('stick');
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of the directive is to add a class ***stick*** if user scroll below header. As a result, table header should be visible for user, even if he scroll long table. *stick* class look like that:

```
.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
}
```

and part of my **some.component.html** (and use directive on thead element) look like:

```
<table class=" table table-bordered ">
 <thead sticky>
   <tr>
    <th width="40%">Name
    </th>
    <th width="10%">Priority
    </th>
    <th width="25%">Date created
    </th>
    <th width="25%">Date modified
    </th>   </tr>   </thead>   <tbody>   <tr *ngFor="let r of entitiesFiltered">
    <td>
      <div class="table-cell-flex">
        <div class="cell-content">
          {{r.name}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="table-cell-flex">
        <div class="cell-content">
          {{r.priority}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
...
```

My code meet basic functionality. It means that header stays in the same place during scroll page, but header width and columns width change. It's look like:[image]

---

**Question:**

Anyone can tell me how can I should style my table, that fixed header does not change form/shape table? Is it possible?

Comment: You need to give it a `width` and/or `left` and `right` values that match the "container" size. Can you link to this or recreate that page for us, or tell me how the main table is centered?

Comment: When  your header gets position:fixed, it takes the element out of the html flow so... it's NOT linked to the table anymore. Take it as if your thead is now a diferent table from your tbody... so set up a same width to BOTH tbody and thead and do not add width JUST to the th but also to the td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get width any columns with javaScript then setting to header with px in position fixed or absolute,
or with html and code:

```
<div class="table-wrapper content">
  <!-- overall wrapper -->
  <table>
    <!-- header -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table-body-wrapper" style="position: relative; overflow: visible;">
  <!-- the element with the custom scrollbar -->
  <table>
    <!-- body -->
    <tbody>
      <!-- auto-generated data (see js function below) -->
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, Column 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 3, Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 3, Column 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 4, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 4, Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 4, Column 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 5, Column 1</td>
        <td>Row 5, Column 2</td>
        <td>Row 5, Column 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer - is something missing?

Comment: how can i help you?

Comment: Dude... you forgot to paste your js-function!

Comment: Okey, I forget this, but I reading again and complete that,sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
In order to solve it, I created a simple hack where I set the fixed width of columns in sticky header and duplicated the sticky header under the table (in order to preserve the width of column names' content.

My solution is based on **Bootstrap 4** and **Angular 6**.

**example.component.html**:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th #tableColumn1>Column 1</th>
    <th #tableColumn2>Column 2</th>
    <th #tableColumn3>Column 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <td>{{ message.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ message.author }}</td>
    <td>{{ message.created_at }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table" [class.d-none]="!showFixedTableHeader">
  <thead>
  <tr [class.sticky]="showFixedTableHeader">
    <th [width]="tableColumn1.offsetWidth">Column 1</th>
    <th [width]="tableColumn2.offsetWidth">Column 2</th>
    <th [width]="tableColumn3.offsetWidth">Column 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**example.component.ts**

```
import {Component, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  showFixedTableHeader: boolean = false;

  @HostListener('window:scroll')
  onScroll() {
    const pageTopOffset = window.pageYOffset;

    if (pageTopOffset > 285) {
      this.showFixedTableHeader = true;
    } else {
      this.showFixedTableHeader = false;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  onResize() {
    // Do nothing.
    // It will automatically trigger to update the bound properties in template.
  }
}
```

**example.component.css**

```
tr.sticky {
  top: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need the angular directive, it's overriding the styles, which specify the width, when it adds class "stick".

You can just fix the position of your table head and set a higher z-index on it so when it does scroll, the body doesn't show through.

See codepen example:

```
thead{
      position:fixed;
      z-index:2;
      ...
     }

tbody{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:1;
      ...
     }
```

https://codepen.io/ciammarino/pen/vmqzLL

Comment: The issue here is how to "synchronize" body columns width with header columns width ^^ You have hardcoded it via CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I have just discovered:

`position: sticky`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/position#Positionnement_adh%C3%A9rent_(sticky)

Comment: `sticky` does not work on `thead` or `tr` in most of the modern browsers sadly.

Comment: yes, check before https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky if this matches your traffic UAs.

Comment: please remove the codepen link - it is wrong and does not use what you say